Error 5: NOT_FOUND details: '' note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
I am trying to upload some data to a Firestore DataBase by running index.js with Node.js. This is part of the Google codelab to use GenAI with Firebase Genkit: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/tree/main/load-firestore-data
I am using a local setting where I have installed the recommended version packages: Node.js v20.14.0 and nmp 10.8.1. As well as, I have authenticated the local environment with firebase and google cloud
I got the following error:
irina@Irinas-MacBook-Air load-firestore-data % pwd
/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data

irina@Irinas-MacBook-Air load-firestore-data % node index.js compass-app-ebf63
Debugger attached.
Loading ./data/activities.json
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: 
    at callErrorFromStatus (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:193:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:129:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:161:32)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:242:29
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
    at repeat (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:119:13
    at OngoingCallPromise.call (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
    at NormalApiCaller.call (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:112:30
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:433:23)
    at DocumentReference.create (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:332:14)
    at CollectionReference.add (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2854:28)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/index.js:67:61
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/index.js:62:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/index.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/load-firestore-data/index.js:20:12) {
  code: 5,
  details: '',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'x-debug-tracking-id' => [ '2578549913826592919;o=1' ] },
    options: {}
  },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}

Node.js v20.14.0

I was thinking the problem was the dependencies, so I reinstalled the packages using npm install within the Project directory /Users/irina/Coding/Repositorios/codelab-ai-genkit-rag/, so the file package-lock.json and folder node_modules were regenerated. However, the error persist.
When I tried debugging the error, I found the error appear in this line, as part of the first function awaiter. The index.js file is located in the repository related at the beginning.
    function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }

"use strict";
var __awaiter =  (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};

And the detail don't bring additional information, just only an empty field, because it doesn't find anything: 
code: 5,
details: '',
Could someone please help me with this error? I am definitely stuck.

I ran into this problem as well, try running
gcloud auth application-default login

and then try you should be ok to load the default data with
node index.js compass-tutorial

Goodluck!
